# Finding a prime factor.

Tags: number-theory

I have difficulty getting a prime factor for that expression: $5^{2015} + 31^{2015}$ other than "$2$".

Comment: Look at the expression modulo 3.

Comment: Also mod $9$...

Comment: There are at least [18 small prime factors](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000829643831).

Comment: @Charles, nice site!

Comment: Limitated to the first million of primes $$2,3,53,131,311,691,1151,18539,57041,84631,340939,352691,2561651$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  If $n$ is odd, then $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a+b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** $x\equiv y\pmod{p-1}\Rightarrow a^x\equiv a^y\pmod{p}$

This fact allows you to rapidly reduce expressions like yours, and let's us find out that modulo three we get that $$5^{20165}+31^{2015}\equiv 2^1+1^1\equiv 0\pmod{3}$$